# css full image background issue

Tags: css

My webpage have 4 background images, each of them needs to be a full screen. On each background, I have some labels and texts. Here is the CSS code, I will address the issue after the code section.

```
html{
    height:100%;
}

body{
    font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
        color:#fff;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
    height:100%;
}

.section{
    background-attachment:inherit;
    background: no-repeat center center fixed;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

By using this style. All background images can take full screen. However, when I resize the browser window to a small height, my labels $ text on background 1 starts to across background 1 and background 2.
If I delete the "height:100%" or using "min-height:100%" instead. Each background image will never get to full screen but I will not get my labels & text across two consecutive background images when I resize the browser window to a smaller height. Please help

Here is my HTML for the first two image background. I need each image background to take full screen on any device, with my text fields look good on each background. Here my issue is, when I shrink the height of the browser, some text will disappear (covered by the next background) due to the height of the text field > height of browser

```
<!-- Page Top Section -->
<div id="page-top" class="section" data-background-image="/images/background/page-top.jpg" style='background-image: url("/images/background/page-top.jpg");'>
    <div class="pattern height-resize">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="site-title">
                hello I am site title
            </h1><!-- /.site-title -->
            <h2 class="section-title">
                hello I am section-1
            </h2>

            <div class="next-section">
                <a class="go-to-about"><span></span></a>
            </div><!-- /.next-section -->

        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </div><!-- /.pattern -->        
</div><!-- /#page-top -->
<!-- Page Top Section  End -->


<!-- About Us Section -->
<section id="about" class="section" data-background-image="/images/background/about-us.jpg" style='background-image: url("/images/background/about-us.jpg");'>
    <div class="pattern height-resize"> 
        <div class="container">
            <h3 class="section-name">
                <span>
                    SECTION NAME
                </span>
            </h3><!-- /.section-name -->
            <h2 class="section-title">
                SECTION TITLE
            </h2><!-- /.Section-title  -->
            <p class="section-description">
                FJDKLASJLKFJASDKLJFLKSJFLKDJSAKLFJDLKSAJ
            </p><!-- /.section-description -->

            <div class="next-section">
                <a class="go-to-subscribe"><span></span></a>
            </div><!-- /.next-section -->

        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </div><!-- /.pattern -->


</section><!-- /#about -->
<!-- About Us Section End -->
```

section title css:
    .section-title{
        text-align:center;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        font-weight:300;
        font-size:80px;
    }

Comment: As you are discussing a rendering issue with your text/labels, it would be helpful to see your HTML as well as functional code.  Right now we only have a fraction of the total story.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that let's you have 4 backgrounds with 100% height and width on all possible devices?

Comment: yes but more, I will add my html in a minute. Thank you so much for replying

Comment: Hi, please see my edit for the HTML part. Thanks :)

Comment: I see. You need to use media queries or pure viewport units for such case. I'd recommend media queries as they have better browser support and are more flexible. I updated my answer, if you need more info feel free to ask.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I haven't looked at yet but I'll mark your answer as the solution. I'll let you know if there's any problems latter. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want four divs with 100% screen size in width and height with different backgrounds that can accept any HTML inside and will fit all screen sizes, there is traditional way to do so:

Preview: http://codepen.io/kunokdev/pen/LRPPdO

**HTML:**

```
<section>
  <div>Any HTML inside a first div w/ background</div>
  <div>Any HTML inside a second div w/ background</div>
  <div>Third is here too!</div>
  <div>
    <h1>Forth</h1>
    <p>Forth has even more than that!</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
section {
  height: 100%;
}
 div {
   height: 100%;
   background-size: cover;
 }
div:nth-child(1){
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/BMaWw5C.jpg);
}
div:nth-child(2){
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/sznCGw4.jpg');
}
div:nth-child(3){
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/BMaWw5C.jpg);
}
div:nth-child(4){
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/sznCGw4.jpg');
}
```

or else with [viewport](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) units:

**HTML:**

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

So I think you need `background-size: cover;` and maybe a little bit of `background-position` property too. In case your content overflows, consider using `overflow: auto`.

**Additionally:**

If your viewport height and width are smaller than the html inside containers, consider using media queries.

For example if your content overflows when height is 500px use query such as

```
media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
  div {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

Consider using Mozilla Firefox responsive design view when testing. Similar feature exists in Chrome too.

Then your contents will no longer be 100% after viewport max-width of 500px, instead they will be as large as contents inside.

Comment: Hi, please see my last line for the section-title CSS. full screen image background is actually not my problem. The problem is : when I resize my browser's height (very small height). each background image only cover browser's size. So some text on background 1 goes to background 2. Is there a way to fix this? or is there a way to make font size "auto" to make sure the text always looks like it's inside the particular background container?

Comment: Oh I see. In that case you must detect at which points it happens and then use media queries. I will edit my answer when I get to job